# How to fix a 404 page not found with other page

Tags: php, .htaccess

404 page not found. How to fix it? And I want to add `/notfound.php` file.

At this time my `htaccess` file is like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

I want the full code to include `notfound.php` to 404 page not found. I tried to do it but it isn’t working. Please help me to do this. Give me a full code for doing that. I want to include `.php` file only in order to show 404 page not found. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

.htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
```

is all you need for 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem a few days ago and its quite easy to solve.

## Solution

I did not have  a `.htaccess` file in the folder where my files where located. In addition, I tried all methods to solve the issue like clearing the cache and cookies, refreshing the page, checked the server, even went through the system malware check.

I finally added a `.htaccess` file in the folder, with the appropriate configuration. that solved my issue